# Getting the feature information under the mouse (GeoTools)

Tags: java, features, geotools

I'm interested in programmatically finding out information of the features (of a map) under the mouse. I'm using GeoTools for drawing the map using a shapefile. I've first used the following code line by overriding onReportedUpdated().

```
InfoTool tool = new InfoTool() {
        @Override
        public void onReporterUpdated() {
            String text = getTextReporterConnection().getText();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    };
```

But, here I get a full string with all information. Yet, I would like to individually find those feature information.

I've found [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/geotools/mailman/message/7820266/) question, in which it is said that there's no direct API call for this. But since this is a quite old question, I would like to know whether there's any direct API methods to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've followed [selection lab](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/map/style.html#selection) of geotools. Source [here](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/docs/src/main/java/org/geotools/tutorial/style/SelectionLab.java). It would be an answer for this question.